# How to display background-image on entire site

Tags: html, css

Want to display a 200*200 background behind the entire site. I have a `div`, `#sidebar`, and another `div`, `#main`, in the `body`. I wish to display the background on `#main` only. Here is the CSS I wrote to achieve this:

```
#main{
    background-image:url('images/bg02.png');
}
```

It works, but when you get to the bottom, where's there's no content, you can see the default white background. To see this, see my test site [here](http://pomonabeta.comeze.com/contact.html), type in random letters into the search bar, and notice the white background is now seen because there is no content in #main.

How do I overflow the background so that it's still visible, even when there's no content?

Comment: try using the background in body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the white body-background from appearing:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    height: 100%;
}
```

For height: 100% to have an effect on `#main`, its parent also needs to have this setting (and its parent, etc.), or a fixed height.

You could consider moving the background to `body`.

Comment: This did the ticket alright! Though Nick's concise code also, worked. I don't think you necessarliy need to seperate the html/body and #main CSS code. But netherless, you helped me. Thanks mate!

Comment: You are welcome. I would keep them separate as you'll want to apply the background to one or other of them. If you add it to the `body` I would also separate out the rule for `html`.

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly set height of elements you want to be filled with your background.

Try to add to your css code below

```
html,
body,
#main {
  height: 100%;
  }
```